# How to troubleshoot XAML preview error in VS: ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In complex WPF GUI, Visual Studio 2015 draws XAML preview or fails to show sometime. I got below error in XAML preview window, what is the recommended way to find and fix the problem?

```
at System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey(Object key)
at System.Collections.Hashtable.Contains(Object key)
at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Contains(Object key)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInTree(FrameworkElement feStart, FrameworkContentElement fceStart, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, InheritanceBehavior& inheritanceBehavior, Object& source)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(UncommonField`1 dataField, ItemStructList`1& valueLookupList, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, Boolean styleLookup, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromStyleOrTemplate(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()
at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateStyleAndReferences(DependencyObject d, ResourcesChangeInfo info, Boolean containsTypeOfKey)
at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnResourcesChanged(DependencyObject d, ResourcesChangeInfo info, Boolean raiseResourceChangedEvent)
at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnResourcesChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, ResourcesChangeInfo info, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnResourcesChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, ResourcesChangeInfo info)
at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.NotifyOwners(ResourcesChangeInfo info)
at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnMergedDictionariesChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
at System.Windows.ResourceDictionaryCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, ResourceDictionary item)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
```

Comment: To downvoter: I hardly agree this claims as off-topic.

Comment: The Data you're are binding is not valid. Are you using `Design Time` in your Xaml?

Comment: @Smartis // No, I'm not using it. I should try it.

Comment: In above stacktrace, which message tells you `Data you're are binding is not valid`?

Comment: `Missing Key` and `ObservableCollection Item insert`makes me think this. But without Code/Markup is this more like finding a light-switch in a dark room.

Comment: @Smartis // thanks for advising me. Let me try to bind some fake data to it.

Comment: And Yes i would recommend `Design Time` for stability.But i don't have any technical reason for this.